# Xpath parsing the whole page when i specify not to

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm parsing websites using python and XPath.

What I'm trying to do is to extract the href from the `<a>`

So here's how is the XML (page):

```
<div id="post">
  <div align="center">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <td>
            <a href="test01">
        <tr>
          <td>
        <tr>
          <td>
  <div align="center">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <td>
            <a href="test01">
        <tr>
          <td>
        <tr>
          <td>
```

And here's the code I did:

```
posts = page.xpath("//div[@id='posts']/div[@align='center']")
for post in posts :
  print post.xpath("//table/tr[1]/td[2]/a/@href")
```

But the problem is that I end up with every href of `posts` and not the single one from `post`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XPath starting with a `/` character means that it will be begin at the document root node. To create a relative XPath from the context node, you need to put a `.` before the `/`.

So your code should be:

```
posts = page.xpath("//div[@id='posts']/div[@align='center']")
for post in posts:
  print post.xpath(".//table/tr[1]/td[2]/a/@href")
```

Comment: Oh right! I totally forgot about this! Thanks a lot!