# How to Get XML Node

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get a node example as a below:
 How could I get Father's occupation I am using the code

```
oNotificationDoc.Load(sFileName);
oNodeListPerson = oNotificationDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Person");

XmlNode oNodeFather = null;
oNodeFather = oNodeListPerson.Item(2);
 XmlNode oNodeGeneral_temp = oNodeFather.SelectSingleNode("//NmSpace:" + Occupation, nsmgr);
```

But getting the Mother's Occupation in return.

```
<Person DOB="23121964" Role="Mother" ApproxDateOfMarriage="2" DateOfMarriage="10062015" MaritalStatus="1" Nationality="CN" PPSN="" ApproxDOB="2">

    <PersonName Surname="TEST" Forename1="TEST" OtherSurnames="" BirthSurname="TEST"/>

    <MothersBirthSurname>TEST</MothersBirthSurname>

    <Address Type="Residential" Country="IE" County="D07" Line4="" Line3="TEST" Line2="TEST" Line1="TEST"/>

    <Occupation>BARISTA</Occupation>

    <PrevPregDetails PrevSponAbortions="0" PrevLateFetalDeaths="0" PrevChildrenStillLiving="0" PrevLiveBirths="0" ApproxDateOfLastBirth="" DateOfLastBirth=""/>

    </Person>


    <Person DOB="12101972" Role="Father" Nationality="CN" PPSN="" ApproxDOB="2">

    <PersonName Surname="TEST" Forename1="TEST" OtherSurnames="UNKNOWN" BirthSurname="TEST"/>

    <MothersBirthSurname>TEST</MothersBirthSurname>

    <Address Type="Residential" Country="AA" County="" Line4="" Line3="TEST" Line2="TEST" Line1="TEST"/>

    <Occupation>WAITER</Occupation>

    </Person>
```

Comment: Please show how you access `oNodeFather`!

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Please show how you access `oNodeListPerson`!

Comment: Please show what is `MGROXMLConstants.g_cXML_Person`

Comment: Question is updated now

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907688/xpath-parsing-the-whole-page-when-i-specify-not-to/36907792#36907792

Answer (score 0):

To get only Father Role in:

```
<Person DOB="12101972" Role="Father" ...
```

Use XPath expression `/Person[@Role='Father']`.

After you use your code:

```
XmlNode oNodeGeneral_temp = oNodeFather.SelectSingleNode("//NmSpace:" + Occupation, nsmgr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`XPath` can solved you question. About XPath : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

Example code：

```
    var xml = XDocument.Load(sFileName);
    var search = xml.XPathSelectElement("//Person[@DOB='12101972' and @Role='Father']/Occupation");
    Console.WriteLine(search.Value);
```

Comment: More answer see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956831/get-datas-from-xml-document/41957268#41957268

Answer (score 0):

Use linq because its handy and you can do everything.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result = from item in doc.Root.Elements("Person")
              select new { Label = (string)item.Element("Occupation") };
```

I've tested this code and it works with your given xml.